# Olog(n) Search in File

Tags: ruby, algorithm

This is more of an educational question. I have a `txt` file, which has a lot of strings in it:

```
string
string1
string2
string3
...
```

And I need to check whether the message that user send has any string from that list in it.
Easy way would be to do like this:

```
message.body.include?(words)

def words
  File.readlines(Rails.root.join('path','to','file.txt'), chomp: true)
end
```

So there in the `words` I have a list of words and I simply check the whole list. However, what if I have a very long list and the value that I need is `length(list) - 1`?

I know that there is a better algorithm for such kind of search, however I do not completely understand how to implement it or use it. One of my fellow students suggested using hash tables, but I can't understand what benefit it would bring? Thanks!

Comment: This list, is it sorted?

Comment: No. it's random

Comment: If the list isn't sorted, you can't do better than O(n). If the list is sorted, binary search is extremely efficient O(log n), but sorting the list takes O(n log(n)), so it only helps if you're doing lots of lookups or can otherwise maintain a sorted list. Hash tables won't beat a linear search unless you have multiple lookups after reading the file--it takes O(n) to build the hash table, then O(1) to look up the entry to see if it's present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using `Trie` data-structure. From [Hackerearth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/trie-keyword-tree/tutorial/):

> A Trie is a special data structure used to store strings that can be visualized like a graph. It consists of nodes and edges. Each node consists of at max 26 children and edges connect each parent node to its children.

If you are not familiar with `Trie`, then I would highly suggest you to read about it first. In your case, your file contains a list of words. Then you need to search for the existence of another string in your file. You can first build the `Trie` with all the strings of the file. The complexity of this operation would be `O(number_of_total_characters_in_the_file)`. Then for every search-string, you can search for the existence with `O(Len(search-string))`.

Please keep in mind, `Trie` would only help you if you have multiple search-strings to lookup into the file. Otherwise the build time of the `Trie` would be a wastage.